# CREATE2 in UniswapV2Factory contract returns zero address on my test network

Tags: solidity

My function in a contract is responsible for creating a liquidity pair on uniswapV2. Unfortunately, the "CREATE2" opcode in the createPair function of the UniswapV2Factory contract does not work. It always returns the zero address when testing it on a proof of authority network to mock a normal testnet.

Background:

- My unit tests are working with the hardhat network.
- I have also included the block number in the salt for CREATE2 to exclude multiple creations. In the final transaction, it will definitely be called only once. Additionally, it is checked in the calling contract whether a pair already exists.
- I have tried it without and with the optimizations for the 0.5.16 compiler in the hardhat.config.ts.
- I deploy the contracts and make the calls from a script written by myself to be independent of my frontend (where I found the issue first).
- I have taken the values with which I create from my unit tests. I only had to make the time variable because my POA network continues to run.
- Since the POA network continues to run, I also have new addresses every time. I deploy all contracts anew for each test.